# React Native - How to set width of Views inside ScrollView to fit?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have multiple Views inside my horizontal ScrollView. How can I set them such that each of those views has the exact dimensions as that of the ScrollView? 
I want to use paging and go to my next View inside the ScrollView on swiping. I have tried to use `width : "100%"` but it does not work as ScrollView does not have fixed dimensions, but that is basically what I want to do with the views inside it. Here is my code:

```
export default class HorizontalScrollView extends Component {
    render () {
    screenWidth = "100%"
        return ( 
            <ScrollView 
            contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollable}
            horizontal={true}
            snapToInterval={screenWidth}
            decelerationRate={"fast"}
            >
                <View style={StyleSheet.compose(styles.insideContainer, {"width" : screenWidth, "backgroundColor" : "red"})}>
                    <Text>Screen 1</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={StyleSheet.compose(styles.insideContainer, {"width" : screenWidth, "backgroundColor" : "blue"})}>
                    <Text>Screen 3</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={StyleSheet.compose(styles.insideContainer, {"width" : screenWidth, "backgroundColor" : "green"})}>
                    <Text>Screen 2</Text>
                </View>
            </
```

StyleSheet:

```
styles = StyleSheet.create({
    "scrollable" : {
        "backgroundColor" : "black",
        "height" : "100%"
    },
    "insideContainer" : {
        "alignItems" : "center",
        "justifyContent" : "center",
        "flex" : 1,
    }
})
```

P.S. - I am using an Android Samsung Galaxy M30 to test this.

Any help or explanation would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code use these styles to accomplish what you want

```js
<ScrollView horizontal={true} snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('screen').width} contentContainerStyle={{minHeight: '100%'}}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={{width: Dimensions.get('screen').width, height: Dimensions.get('screen').height, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
          <Text>Screen 1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{width: Dimensions.get('screen').width, height: Dimensions.get('screen').height, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
          <Text>Screen 2</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{width: Dimensions.get('screen').width, height: Dimensions.get('screen').height, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
          <Text>Screen 3</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your scroll view is the width of the screen, you can set each view inside to have a width of

```
Dimensions.get(“screen”).width
```

Then set the pagingEnabled prop of the ScrollView to true and you should have a paging scroller with full width sub views.